# Thread-safety in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to write a high performance synchronized generator in C.  I want to be able to feed events to it and have multiple threads be able to poll/read asynchronously, such that threads never receive duplicates.

I don't really know that much about how synchronization is typically done.  Can someone give me a high level explanation of one or more techniques that I might be able to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concept in thread safety is the **[Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)** (though there is different kind of locks).
It is used to protect your memory from multiple accesses and race conditions.

A good example of its use would be when using a [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). You can't allow two different threads to modify it in the same time. In your example, you could possibly use a linked-list to create a queue, and each thread would consume some data from it.

Obviously there are other synchronization mechanisms, but this one is (by far ?) the most important.

You could have a look at [this](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) page (and referenced pages at the bottom) for more implementation details.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think this is the concept I had forgotten to remember.  Since I want this to work where the client is on a different machine, as well as when the client is in a separate thread, I'm not 100% sure that thread-based synchronization is going to work, although it may.

Comment: Maybe you should have a better idea of what you are trying to do, and how you are going to do it. Even considering you have many clients on the same machine, should you be running different threads or different processes ? It is not that clear.

Comment: I'm definitely still working through exactly how the application should be laid out.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a [thread implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#Implementations); C does not have any built-in support for multiprocessing concepts. Threads are thus often implemented as libraries. Such a library will typically provide you with ways to synchronize the execution of multiple threads, ways to protect data, and so on.

Comment: Is it impossible to synchronize in an implementation-independant way?  I only ask because I don't know much about the rest of my architecture yet--I suspect there may be a system mode where the events are pulled over the network, so the synchronization might be taking place between machines instead of between threads within a single parent process.  Does this make a significant difference?

Comment: Your two seperate machines don't share memory so you should be OK here.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense.  Synchronization in this case would be in the TCP stack or socket processing code.

Answer (score 0):

Thread-safe will be the problem when there are shared variables between threads. If you don't have any shared variables, it's not a problem. Every event can be readonly and disptaching to listeners randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is achieved by using whatever synchronisation primitives the multithreading implementation provides.

Your start point would probably be a linked list of events, a lock that protects it, and every thread takes the lock, consumes one event by adjusting the pointer to the first event and then releases the lock; appending events also locks the entire list. When the list is empty, the workers exit.

From there, various optimisations are possible:

- Caching the pointer to the last event, so appending an event to the list becomes cheaper.
- Adding a notification mechanism so worker threads can sleep while the list is empty. Typically, this is achieved with something called a *condition variable*.
- Using multiple lists, so if the first list is locked, the worker can retrieve an event from another list without having to wait for the thread that has currently locked the list.